# How to force a bottleneck in an autoencoder to produce binary values?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder, loss-function

I try to force a bottleneck layer in an autoencoder to produce binary values. I'm doing it by using `tensorflow.cond` in a custom loss function, penalizing all values which are not 0 or 1. However this method is very slow. Is there a better way to perform this?

```
def custom_loss(weight):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        reconstruction_loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

        def binarize_loss(value):
            return tf.cond(tf.reduce_mean(value) > 0.5, lambda: tf.abs(value - 1), lambda: tf.abs(value))

        binarized_loss_value = tf.map_fn(binarize_loss, neckLayer.output)
        return reconstruction_loss + (K.mean(binarized_loss_value , axis=-1) * weight)

    return loss
```

Comment: What do you mean by very slow ? Taking too much time to converge, on slowing down your training process ? (i.e it takes now more time to do an epoch). For the first problem, I guess that one option would be to add more weight to the `binarize_loss` function by multiplying it by a constant > 1.

Comment: The influence of the binarizing function is anyway regulated via the weight and increases over time. However the training process per epoch is much slower. Tensorflow has to branch between the two cases for each value in that layer. This is quite time consuming during training as GPUs seems to be not made for branching. Maybe there is a more streamlined, GPU friendly function possible? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably get rid of the `tf.cond` statement, as you can do what you want by using simple arithmetic :

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        reconstruction_loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

        binary_neck_loss = tf.abs(0.5 - tf.abs(0.5 - neckLayer.output))

        return reconstruction_loss + (K.mean(binary_neck_loss , axis=-1) * weight)
```

Of course, I don't know exactly the shape of your data, but you should be able to extrapolate from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What a beautiful simple solution. Ashamed double facepalm.